# QT app i made exited with code -1073741515

Tags: qt

I have coded a program in QTcreator on linux and when i tried to port it to windows. 
Program compiles without any errors.
But when i run the program it exits automatically
Starting C:\Projects\LIG\debug\LIGenerator.exe...

C:\Projects\LIG\debug\LIGenerator.exe exited with code -1073741515

I tried to debug it using QT creator debugger. But flow of the program  does not pass even through main.cpp

how to debug the program and fine where is the errors.

---

**Update**

In the .pro file the INCLUDEPATH and LIB are the following

```
win32:INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files\Expat 2.0.1\Source\lib"
win32:INCLUDEPATH += "E:\confuse-2.7\confuse-2.7\src"
win32:INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Projects\LithologyInputGenerator5\XML"
win32:LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/Expat 2.0.1/Bin" \
    -L"C:/Program Files/GnuWin32/lib/" \
    -L"E:/confuse-2.7/confuse-2.7/windows/msvs.net/libConfuse/Release" 
LIBS += -lexpat \
    -lcrypto \
    -lssl\
    -lconfuse
unix:LIBS += libgsoap++.a \
    -lgsoap
win32:LIBS += -lwsock32
```

---

**Update**

I have  used dependency walker as mentioned which help me to find the missing dependencies. I have now fixed all the dependencies except MPR.DLL ( Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.). IT was not missing so i left it out.
Also i have used a configuration  file. I have now copied the conf file to debug dir for WIN32 compiler.I don't remember whether i have used more than one conf file
Still the program automatically exit with code -1073741515
. I tried to debug program using GUI debugger . But program is not even breaking at main also.

Could any one help me to get out of the this?

Answer (score 22):

-1073741515 is the same as 0xC0000135 which I think often is because a a dependency is missing. I'd suggest checking that all DLLs your app depends on are in the correct locations.

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for this.

Comment: When I saw this exit code it was the only hint provided by a program run in the background without access to the Windows GUI (because it was run by another program).  I tried to run the program directly from the Command Prompt and it popped up an error window explaining exactly which DLL was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, fixed by changing project settings Projects -> Tool chain -> MinGW (x86 32bit)