# Application won't launch from Creator

Tags: windows, qt

my Qt application won't launch from Qt Creator, however I can run the .exe directly from the release folder. Why is that ? I am totally lost here. In Qt Creator, I just get a message telling me that my application just crashed, with the code -1073741515.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt Creator must be pointing to the wrong dlls.  You could reinstall the QtSDK and it should fix finding the runtime dlls in the IDE (Qt Creator).

[http://www.daniweb.com/.../ok-so-whats-error-1073741515-again](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/233908/ok-so-whats-error-1073741515-again)

On this post [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28535-exited-with-code-1073741515) they said they fixed it by updating the PATH in Qt.  Here is the portion that gets prepended to my PATH variable as seen in the picture below:

```
C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin;C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\lib;C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\bin;
```

Here is a screenshot showing how to access that:

[image]

Another option is you could go into the QtSDK folder, find the bin folder for compiler and platform you are using and put it in the path for your system.  Then Qt should be able to run the program just by finding the dlls in the system path.

[image]

Possibly the shortest option, but the trickiest would be to go into Qt Creator > Tools > Options > Qt4 and make sure you have something that looks similar to this:

[image].

Comment: Hi, I've just reinstalled Qt Creator, to add the MSVC compilers. "Another option is you could go into the QtSDK folder, find the bin folder for compiler and platform you are using and put it in the path for your system. Then Qt should be able to run the program just by finding the dlls in the system path." I did that too...

Comment: Yep, I actually did my homeworks before I came posting here :)

Comment: "well i found what was wrong ... i manually "reset" the "path" variable in QTCreator ... now everything works fine..." is written in that post.  I'll add a screenshot where I found that path argument for me.

Comment: uhuh ! The guy spent 2 days on that one ! Problem solved for me, thank you very much guys, I indeed had to edit the Qt Creator path variable, I had forgot about it and thought that the Windows environment variable was the one to edit... O__O many thx!!!

Answer (score 1):

Going by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360888/qt-app-i-made-exited-with-code-1073741515) it looks as if it's failing to find a shared library.

Check the appropriate path environment variable in the project's run settings and make sure it's got everything it needs.

Comment: What bothers me most is that I can launch my application (.exe) from the release folder... it then works fine, exept that it crashes when I close it... O__O

Comment: I gave a try to Dependency Walker, which I didn't know, and it's telling me that my application can't find GPSVC.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL

Comment: @CTZStef: Yes, because your path environment is different when you do that or Windows is looking in the current directory and finding what it needs. The run environment in QtCreator _must_ be set correctly. Just because it runs in some other environment does not guarantee anything.

Comment: So what should I do ? What do you suggest ?

Comment: @CTZStef: Are you saying that you have checked the run environment in QtCreator and you are completely satisified that it is correct? (BTW, to avoid any confusion, my first comment was in response to your first comment, not your second.)

Comment: Nope, thanks to you Troubadour, it wasn't clear to me wether Qt Creator was using the Widows path environment variable or not, and I (re)discovered that I had to edit the PATH variable in Qt Creator. I had completly forgot about it. Everything is fine now... thanks again!  I still find it kind of weird though, Windows or Qt Creator path ...