# QT is failing to build ui_mainwindow.h, error 135 (-1073741515)

Tags: c++, qt

My QT5.1.1 project used to build with qt creator but when I came into work today it no longer worked. To my knowledge, nothing has changed since the last time I was on. A co-worker needed to use my workstation earlier this week and says that he did not change anything.

The error shows up as:

```
[ui_mainwindow.h] Error -1073741515
```

I did a Google search and tried a few things.

[This](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/31667) page said to try a clean build and run qMake then rebuild. This did not work even after trying multiple times.

[This](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53324-ui_mainwindow-h-file-not-found) page led to the suggestion of adding  QT += widgets to the .pro file (although I did not believe this would work I tried anyways)

I also tried closing the project and re-opening it. I deleted the build directory and that didn't work either.

EDIT:

I added error code 135 because according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360888/qt-app-i-made-exited-with-code-1073741515/3360923#3360923) answer on stack overflow the two are related. I have not encountered or seen this error code come up. I have downloaded the dependency walker but I am not sure how to use it.

After a clean start up I get the following pop up when opening a project.

[Image of error pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttRHy.png)

Comment: Have you tried checking if there are copies of the auto-generated files somewhere in the build pipeline? See http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3438

Comment: The number in your title doesn't match the number in the error message (10 digits vs. 11 digits). I think the one in the title is a typo.

Comment: The obvious question is: what piece of software is reporting this error. The C++ compiler? moc? What?

Comment: If you're using Qt Creator, go to the bottom then click 'Compile Output'. That might give you more of a clue, or some further information to add on to the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, the number in the title is a typo. The number in the question details is correct.

Comment: @ContingencyCoder I have tried the solution found on that page (it is the same solution as the one found on the page I posted) and it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @NicholasSmith The compile output displays the error as follows:

Makefile.Debug:446: recipe for target 'ui_mainwindow.h' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [ui_mainwindow.h] Error -1073741515

Any clues?

Comment: For future reference, you can edit your question, including the title, to correct any errors. (I've done it for you this time.)

Comment: Your title mentions "error 135", but the body of your question doesn't. Please show the complete error message in the body of your question.

Comment: @KeithThompson used a friends account to add some more information and links. Error 135 should be explained and I added an image of an error that might help. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `-1073741515`, when normalized by adding 2**32, is `0xc0000135`; that's probably where the "135" comes from.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes. Thank you. It turns out a coworker accidentally moved a bunch of DLLs from my mingw bin directory. So I added them back and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that a coworker accidentally moved a bunch of DLLs out of my MinGW bin directory. I had to move them back.

Comment: I always seem to have problems with DLLs and MinGW. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Yeah. He did mean to move some DLLs (and what he intended would have been fine) but he accidentally grabbed a bunch of core DLLs.