# .exe gives error MSVCP120.dll is missing for Win7x64

Tags: visual-studio, dll, linker, visual-studio-2013

I created .exe using VS2013 and I added it directly to control panel by giving registry path. I built it for x64. It launches perfectly fine for Win8.1x64. But when I launches it on Win7x64 it gives MSVCP120.dll error. If I copy dll it works. But does the dll's are connected directly to .exe? If not how do I attach them?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your error just means that the MSVC redistributable for VS2013 is missing from the Windows 7 computer. Windows 7 doesn't have this DLL by default.

However, please don't copy DLLs around willy-nilly. You need to make sure the redistributable is installed either as part of your installer or separately by the user. For example, you can have your installer detect the existence or not of the redistributable and alert the user to install it. You could include it with your installation package, which is allowed.

Note that there are 2 versions of the redistributable, for x86 and x64. You need to supply the right one(s) for your application. You can use [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40784) to download the Visual C++ redistributable packages for Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Yes, I have x64 but I am trying to figure out how to add them to application through Visual Studio 2013

Comment: You can either link dynamically to the DLL, which requires that the redistributable is installed on the installation computer, or you can statically link it into your executable. Static linking will increase the size of your executable but will mean that you don't rely on the redistributable being installed before your program can run. What to do and how is up to you.

Comment: I think static link it best option...do I just add .dll in linker?

Comment: It's an option you can select in your solution settings. [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749662/microsoft-visual-studio-c-c-runtime-library-static-dynamic-linking) has an interesting discussion with regards to static/dynamic linking in Visual Studio.

Comment: If the program has no access to the Windows GUI (because it was run in the 'background' by another program) it will not print any error message.  Instead, the exit code is -1073741515.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3360923/2950621

Answer (score 22):

Even if you're using x64, you need to install also x86 version of MSVC redistributable.

I had this problem myself as well. I found that even after installing x64 version of MSVC redistributable, the `msvcp120.dll` file was missing in SysWOW64 directory. The issue was solved after installing also x86 version.

Comment: For me this was an issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thx, this is very useful because in others answers just say "install MSVC again", but don't specify if is for x86 or x64 like in the most case of moderns computers

Comment: For me, I had to install the x86 for last, only then it worked.